# Run Play application dist in production as daemon

Tags: daemon, playframework-2.3

With my Play application built with command `activator stage`, I want to deploy it to production server. However, when I use the start script to start the app, it seems the app is not forked into a separated JVM. Thus if I try Ctrl+C, it will kill the app. Ctrl+D does not do anything, unlike when I use the command `activator start`, where Ctrl+D is used to detach from the log.

Is there anyway to run the Play app as daemon in production (with no SBT, Activator installed)?

Comment: Not at all. I don't install activator in prod machine.

Comment: Read the answers. Its all about running play as subprocess of `nohup`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system, install it as a service ( in /etc/init.d for example), use a tool like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html). There are plenty of other options as well